# Django / HTTP - Sending query string with a POST request - Is it not recommended?

Tags: django, http, post, request, query-string

This is my models.py:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class BlogExtended(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    usersVoted = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

Basically, each blog has a user who created the blog. If users like someones blog, they can vote for it. Each time a blog gets a vote, the 'votes' counter goes up by one. In my template, I don't want the vote button to be a button which just says 'vote'. I want the vote button to be an image. Since once the user clicks the vote button, I am going to be altering the database (increasing the 'votes' field by one) I need to use a POST request.
So this is what I initially had for my template (I initially used a GET request):

```
{% if Blogs %} <!-- Blogs is a list of blogs -->
     <ul class="blogs">
     {% for blog in Blogs %}
         <li>
             <a href="/vote/?id={{ blog.id }}" class="vote"><img src="images/voteButton.jpg" </a>
```

and this was my view which handles the /vote/ url:

```
def voteView(request):
     if request.GET.has_key('id'): #if it is a GET request which has the blogs id
         try:
             id = request.GET['id']
             blog = Blog.objects.get(id=id) #if the Blog is found
             blog.votes += 1 #make a change to the 'votes' field in the DB
             blog.blogextended_set.usersVoted.add(request.user) #make a change in the 'usersVoted' field in the DB
             blog.save()
```

but as you can see, I was using GET instead of POST. I realized I needed to use POST since I am altering the database, so this was my attempt at making it a POST request:

```
<form method="post" action="/vote/">{% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">
        <img src="images/voteButton.jpg" alt="vote" /> 
            <!-- I used button rather than input because with button, I was able to replace the button with an image.. I was unable to replace the button with an image -->
    </button>
</form>
```

This form sends basically no information to /vote/ (it only sends the current user object: request.user). I need to also send the ID of the blog. I was able to send the ID the intial way by adding a query string in the URL of the GET request. The only way I can think of to add the ID of the blog in my POST request is by adding a query string in the URL, so my form would action like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/vote/?id={{ blog.id }}">
```

I realized that sending a query string with a POST request is something I have never seen / done before. Is it okay if I send a query string with a POST request or is it not recommended? What problems could arise from sending a query string with a POST request?

Additional help: If it is not recommend, can anyone suggest another way of sending additional information along with the POST request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add another field to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="blog_id" value="{{ blog.id }}" />
```

whole form:

```
<form method="post" action="/vote/">{% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">
        <img src="images/voteButton.jpg" alt="vote" /> 
    </button>
    <input type="hidden" name="blog_id" value="{{ blog.id }}" />
</form>
```

then, your view should look like:

```
def voteView(request):
     if request.POST.has_key('blog_id'): 
         try:
             id = request.POST['blog_id'] 
             ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The better solution is the put the blog ID in a hidden field in your form, like so:

```
<form method="post" action="/vote/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ blog.id }}">
    <button type="submit">
        <img src="images/voteButton.jpg" alt="vote" />
    </button>
</form>
```

In your view, you will be able to extract the ID of the blog post that was voted for using `request.POST['id']`.

Comment: I'd upvote this if you didn't include using `request.POST[]`
Let me repeat for everyone again: accessing POST items directly is an anti-pattern, it might be acceptable in some cases but usually it's just doing it wrong by being lazy. 
You need to pass data to `forms.Form` class that will clean and validate data.  Inserting unvalidated data into DB might work, not be a security risk generally, but it will come and bite you later, and it might be hard.
Don't think just make it a habit. Any data input goes into form for validation.